# Shorten long code lines containing anchor tags in HTML

Tags: html, url

I want a max character length of 80 characters on my text. It is being stopped by long, long links to which I can not find a way to shorten down in the actual code. Not on the website, but the actual code. Just to make it look cleaner and shorter and without the use of websites like shorturl.

An example of a long link that i have is this.

```html
<a href="https://www.ukrinform.net/rubric-polytics/3308431-usukraine-strategic-partnership-commission-to-meet-this-fall.html">
```

But i want to be able to like cut it in half in the code so it displays for example like this:

```html
<a href="https://www.ukrinform.net/rubric-polytics
/3308431-usukraine-strategic-partnership-commission-to-meet-this-fall.html">
```

All I am getting is errors with it taking on the first part of the link that contains the line break. I can not find any way to fix the problem.

I wonder if there is any possible way I can get done something similar.

Comment: If its for a display purpose, just use an editor that split lines at 80 chars. If its for the 80-Len BP, its not considered as a BP since decades :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

You can use something like a url shortener, and then past the shortened link in your code.

##### URL shorteners

- https://bit.ly
- https://shorturl.a
- https://cutt.ly

#### Option 2

You can create another webpage with a list of the links and and use a GET request to access them.

If you are using `PHP`:

```
<script>
    const links = [
                   "https://long-link-1.com",
                   "https://long-link-2.com",
                   "https://long-link-3.com"
                  ]
    window.location.replace(links[<?php echo $_GET["linkID"]; ?>-1])
</script>
```

display web page (Example):

```
<a href="/longlinks.php?linkID=1"></a>
```

Comment: yes. but short url's are temporary are they not? i used one once, then later it just led to the actual webpage of the shorturl company because the link was not working anymore as a shortlink because it had expired

Comment: when i paste in the script, it just says it expected javascript but got PhP.

Comment: is this in the console?

Comment: It works fine when I run it. Can you send me a screenshot?

Comment: sure. ill get a screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236961/discussion-between-topsoftwarepro-and-roald-andre-kvarv).